# Find the item with the biggest value in a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

I'm implementing some logic to get the closest Beacon and to do that I created a Dictionary where I insert some Measures. My problem is that I don't know how to get the item with the biggest value. Some code below:

```
struct objBeacon {
    var accuracy : Float
    var rssi : Float
    var positionInList : Float
}

var readBeacons = [String:objBeacon]()
```

My goal is to get the item (objBeacon) with the biggest `rssi` value, how can I do that without looping through the list?

Comment: I would like to know if there is something like a lamda expression, Ex: beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.unknown }

Comment: Check my answer for  the simplest way.

Comment: But `filter` loops. How did you think it worked? Magic?

Comment: @matt I know it loops, I just dont want to put the loop code in the code. The native filter is probably better than creating you own loop

Comment: Well, the `max` method loops for you and you can supply your own definition function just like `filter`, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is this

```
readBeacons.values.max()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah you will kind of have to loop.

Comment: Not kind of. Will.

Comment: I dont understand how you are meant to fetch a dict value without looping.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the one I expected. I know it loops, but I prefer to do the loops in one line instead of 15. That's what people didn't understand about my question

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to get the item (objBeacon) with the biggest rssi value, how can I do that without looping through the list?

You cannot do it "without looping through the list". What you have is a list, and examining one element with respect to all the others means looping. You may not have to write the loop *explicitly* — for example, you could call the `max(by:)` method, which lets you do for `max` the same sort of thing `filter` does — but there will be a loop, regardless.

Comment: @crashoverride777 Which loops, as I said.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was actually meant for his question, not your answer.